# create fileinputstream for the nested jar files i.e jar inside jar

Tags: java, jar, fileinputstream, md5sum, sha1sum

there is a nested jar in the jar, like this :

```
jar:file:/home/inct-venkates/work/workspace/WebGoat/webgoat-server/target/webgoat-server-v8.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar!/
```

finally what I'm looking for is I need to create `md5`, `sha1`, `sha256` for the nested jar file.
please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: You don’t need a FileInputStream;  you just need an InputStream.  Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar.

Comment: i tried new FileInputStream(new File(file)) ...but is is giving exception no such a file..

Comment: if i create just InputStream..i can't calculate the md5,sha1..so FileInputStream is requied.